# Linux socket modes of IO

Tags: io, tcp, socket, interrupt

There are three modes of i/o. They are Programmed IO, Interrupt IO and DMA.

My understanding is, Programmed IO requires CPU to busy-wait while Interrupt IO by nature, is ansynchronous.

Where can I find out which IO mode or whether it is configurable that which IO mode would be used by Linux synchronous and asynchronous socket, we can use TCP socket as an example.

Comment: Start with `man -a socket`.